# How to make favicon icon transparent?

Tags: html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="C:\Users\Melvin\Pictures\kaka.png">
    <title>Cookie Clicker!</title>
<body>
```

My image is in png format in my files buy my favicon icon is not transparent

Comment: What is the point of a transparent icon?

Comment: i dont want to have white around it

Comment: you need your png to have transparent background then create a .ico file from it using something like https://favicon.io/

Comment: You cannot manipulate images in plain HTML.